# Android Custom View Redraw remove previous

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, custom-view

I need to redraw the triangular indicator wherever i touch in the View but the previous one doesn't get removed. What should i do?
I just update the midpoint of the triangle `onTouch` of the View and the other two points gets updated based on this point. I have tried `Mode.CLEAR` and `invalidate()` everywhere.

**My Custom View**

```
/**
 * Created by Shuvam Ghosh on 8/26/2017.
 */

public class IndicatorView extends View {

private RectF mRect;
private Paint mRectPaint;
private Paint mCirclePaint;
private int noOfTabs;
private Path triangle;
private PointF leftpt;
private PointF midpt;
private PointF rightpt;
private Bitmap  [] imgRes;
private int [] resources;
private float defval = ((float)getWidth()/3)/2;



public IndicatorView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(null);
}

public IndicatorView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(attrs);
}

public void setResources(int [] res){
    this.resources = res;
    Log.d("Size of imgres",""+resources.length);
}


public IndicatorView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(attrs);
}

public IndicatorView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init(attrs);
}

public void init(@Nullable AttributeSet set){

    resources = new int[noOfTabs];
    mRect = new RectF();
    mRect.left = 0;
    mRect.top = 0;
    mRect.bottom = 140;
    triangle = new Path();
    leftpt=new PointF();
    midpt=new PointF();
    rightpt=new PointF();



    Log.d("Size of imgres in init",""+resources.length);
    leftpt.x=0;
    leftpt.y=0;

    midpt.x=((float)getWidth())/2 ;
    midpt.y=0;

    rightpt.x=0;
    rightpt.y=0;

    //bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp);

    mRectPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mRectPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#e7ab33"));
    mRectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mCirclePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mCirclePaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    if(set == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    TypedArray ta = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(set , R.styleable.IndicatorView);
    noOfTabs = ta.getInteger(R.styleable.IndicatorView_no_of_sections,3);
    mCirclePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    ta.recycle();

}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    mRect.right = getWidth();


    canvas.drawRect(mRect,mRectPaint);
    Log.d("No of tabs=",""+noOfTabs);
    Log.d("X-axis value=",""+(2/(float)noOfTabs));
    Log.d("midptx value=",""+midpt.x);


    midpt.y = 168;

    leftpt.x = midpt.x - 35;
    leftpt.y = 140;
    rightpt.x = midpt.x + 35;
    rightpt.y = 140;
    triangle.lineTo(leftpt.x, leftpt.y);
    triangle.lineTo(midpt.x, midpt.y);
    triangle.lineTo(rightpt.x,rightpt.y);
    canvas.drawPath(triangle,mRectPaint);



    Log.d("Size of imgres inOndraw",""+resources.length);
    imgRes = new Bitmap[noOfTabs];
    for(int i=0; i<resources.length; i++)
    {
        imgRes[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),resources[i]);
    }
    canvas.drawBitmap(imgRes[0],(getWidth()/noOfTabs)/2-(imgRes[0].getWidth()),70-(imgRes[0].getHeight())/2,null);
    for(int i =1; i<noOfTabs; i++) {
       // canvas.drawCircle((i / (float) noOfTabs) * getWidth(), 66, 6, mCirclePaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(imgRes[i],(i / (float) noOfTabs) * getWidth()+(getWidth()/noOfTabs)/2-(imgRes[i].getWidth()/2),70-(imgRes[i].getHeight())/2,null);
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   // return super.onTouchEvent(event);

    int eventAction = event.getAction();

    // you may need the x/y location
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();

    // put your code in here to handle the event
    switch (eventAction) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            drawNewArrow();
            midpt.x = x;
            Log.d("Touched at",""+(x*3)/getWidth());
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            break;
    }
   // postInvalidate();
    return false;
}
}
```

Screenshot

[image]